# Unable to hit click event for button used in ag-grid Cell Renderer in angular 8

Tags: angular8, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using below code: 
Can someone please let me know whats incorrect in this?

```
 {headerName: 'Status', field: 'RequestCategory' , 
tooltip: (p: any) => {
  return 'Download';
},
cellRenderer: CellRendererFunc, editable : false}


function CellRendererFunc(params) {
  return '<button style="background:none !important;border: none;  padding: 0 !important; color: #7c77ad; cursor: pointer;  text-decoration: underline;  text-underline-position: under;" (click)="loadRequestsHistory(id)">'+params.value+'</button>';
}

function loadRequestsHistory(id) {
      this.accountTransferAuditHistoryService.GetRequestIdDetailsByBatch(id).
        subscribe(res => {
          this.BindRequestsTable(res,id);
          this.blockUI.stop();
        },
          (err) => this.handleMessageError(err));
    }
```

I am able to see button on my grid but its not hitting the button click event

Comment: I have got the answer for this. Unable to fix with above code. Had to create separate component for button cell renderer and it worked.
For reference, https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/